# Regular Expression Problem

Tags: automata, regular-languages, regular-expressions

Question is

$$\left\{ w | w \text{ contains an even number of } 0\text{s or exactly two }1\text{s} \right\}$$

I need to confirm my answer but i don't from where to ask someone.

My answer is

```
1*(01*0)*+11
```

but i don't know if it's correct or not

Comment: If you don't know whether it's correct or not, try proving that it is correct. We tend not to grade homework on this site.

Comment: You might have misinterpreted the phrase "exactly two 1s", which probably means that your word is allowed to contain an arbitrary number of 0s.

Comment: 1) is the "or" inclusive or exclusive? 2) what is the meaning of your "+" since in most regular expressions it is used differently?

Comment: @Matthias 1. "or" is always inclusive in mathematics, unless clearly stated otherwise. 2. non-superscripted "+" is a common notation for "or" in regular expressions; otherwise usually written "|".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request to check an answer with no specific question about the answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby was only familiar with the superscript: a(a)* \equiv a+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression is close to correct for the 'even number of zeros' part; you just forgot the string could end in ones.  I.e:

```
1*(01*0)*1* + 11 [where 'exactly two ones' means precisely that]
```

or

```
1*(01*0)*1* + 0*10*10* [where 'exactly two ones' implies any number of zeros]
```